# react-flickity-component@3.0.3 requires a peer of react@~16.0.0

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-modules, package.json

I get that message every time when try to run npm install. Can someone help me with solving the issue?
[image]

as per warning i should install the react@16.0.0, react-dom@16.0.0 but i already have the latest versions in my package.json react@^16.4.1, react-dom@^16.4.1